# Node.Js 500+ Item Searching

Tags: node.js, alexa-voice-service

I am working on an Alexa skill, for my own skill building, education, and some fun.

What I'm aiming for is for Alexa to provide a value based on two values provided by the user.  The Alexa to Lambda Node.js function is all up and working in Dev mode but, at the moment always returns the same response.

I have a list of 400+ items, each item has:
A number from one to 10.
X is true or false
Y is true or false
A Description

There will be scope to add additional true or false columns at a later date.

The requirement is to filter the list based on the number and either X or Y, then provide a random description from the filtered list.

Completely new to node.js, and so many options and ways to do this.
what and how would be the best way?
Is it possible to load a CSV file into the Lambda function and query that?
Or should i be building an array within the code itself?

The list is expected to grow over time, but not significantly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways how to solve that. I would suggest you to store your csv file outside of your skill - then you don't need to re-deploy the skill when you change data in the csv file.

**Using [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/?nc=sn&loc=0):**

There is a [blog post](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/68ddfc29-f407-48ec-979b-e94e57d3b3fc/query-amazon-s3-like-a-relational-database-to-provide-fresh-skill-content) with node.js code samples related to your issue at [Alexa Blogs](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa).

When you create [Alexa Hosted](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/build-a-skill-end-to-end-using-an-alexa-hosted-skill.html) skill, there is 5GB of S3 storage assigned to it for free[*](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/build-a-skill-end-to-end-using-an-alexa-hosted-skill.html#usage) and pre-configured to be easily used. I think it's good enough for your use case.